# You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure

I just managed to create a new instance of Sitecore 8.2 on my Azure account.
When I'm going on the administration panel http://mySitecoreinstance/sitecore/, I get this error message : 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Do you know how can I fix that ?

Comment: Thats an iis error. Can you try removing the trailing / and test.

Comment: I recommend adding some screen shots of how your resource group is setup and maybe provide some detail around how you created the web app services (e.g. Marketplace, Powershell, ARM templates, etc.)

Comment: I recently had the same issue immediately after creating the environment through the Powershell scripts. We couldn't see any sign of a restriction in the config files or the Azure portal. Restarting the Web App seemed to resolve the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new instance of Sitecore from the Azure Marketplace, two Web App Service instances of Sitecore are created: A Content Delivery instance, and a Content Management instance.

On the CD instance, the Sitecore login and UI are disabled. When you attempt to access, it will give you the permission denied screen, as you describe.

You need to access Sitecore on the Content Management instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of the instances display this message when I try to go on /sitecore/ section...

Comment: @ThomasGRIESMAR did you ever figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue in my CM/CD instances. When I used the Advanced Tools (Kudu) > Zip Deploy UI to deploy my Sitecore project build, this error appeared. It seems like this method of deployment replaces the files that are updated and removes the ones that were not included in the release zip package. So my solution is just to revert to good ol' FTP or WebDeploy in VS. Always check the file contents in your server, some important files might have been deleted or not existing in the first place. Hope this helps!